# How to return all possible conditional bipartite matchings?

Tags: python, recursion, permutation, matching

Suppose that we have an array `X = (x_1, ..., x_N)` of length `N`. We want to return all possible arrays of length `M` (`M` is fixed), whose elements can be from `(x_1, ..., x_N, NaN)` such that each `x_i` is used at most once and the `x_i` order is preserved. For example, if `N = 3` and `M = 7`, a few possible vectors are

```
 Z = (x_1, NaN, NaN, x_2, x_3, NaN, NaN)
 Z = (NaN, x_1, NaN, NaN, x_3, NaN, NaN)
 Z = (x_3, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)
 Z = (NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)
```

But the following vectors are not acceptable:

```
 Z = (x_1, x_1, NaN, x_2, x_3, NaN, NaN)
 Z = (NaN, x_3, NaN, NaN, x_2, NaN, NaN)
```

This problem can be viewed as matching some of the `x_i`s to locations `1,...,M` such that `x_i`s order is preserved. How can I do this? I was thinking of using a recursive function `f(X, M)` that cuts the vector `Z` at every possible point (`for i in range(1,M+1)`) and then concatenates `f(x_1, i)` (defined as a base case) with `f((x_2, ..., x_N), M-i+1)` (recursion). But this approach does not give unique vectors and I have to remove the duplicates afterward and it is not efficient. Is there a better way to solve this? Maybe using itertools?

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? How will you use such a function?

Comment: @aaaaaa I want to design a function to return all possible `Z`s. It is possible to compute the number mathematically for example for `M = 7` and `N = 3` should give 70 (I think) distinct `Z`s. Later, I want to use the result in other parts of my code.

Comment: I understand your question, but I wanna know maybe the larger problem can be solved easier than you think right now. are you gonna call this generator a lot, for example? why your solution is not efficient enough?

Comment: @aaaaaa I see. Yes, I will call this generator a lot. In my problem, I have `N = 3` fixed but `M` varies (I think from 3 to 10). But maybe I can compute them beforehand and save the generator results in a dictionary.

Comment: still, posting snippet of the code that uses this lists would be helpful. Basically, you have M containers in a row, and you have to fill them up by taking elements one-by-one X1, X2, X3, placing in containers variously?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that should work for you. It is basically iterative filling of `M` boxes by taking elements from list `X`. Default content is `None` in that case, but you should be able to adjust. You can [see how it works on repl](https://repl.it/repls/TraumaticTechnicalServerapplication)

```
N = 3
M = 6

X = range(N) # or example, can be [x1,x2,x3]

for j1 in range(M-N+1):
  for j2 in range(j1+1,M-N+2):
    for j3 in range(j2+1,M):
      r = [None]*M
      r[j1] = X[0]
      r[j2] = X[1]
      r[j3] = X[2]
      print(r)
```

This will produce following output:

```
[0, 1, 2, None, None, None]
[0, 1, None, 2, None, None]
[0, 1, None, None, 2, None]
[0, 1, None, None, None, 2]
[0, None, 1, 2, None, None]
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None]
[0, None, 1, None, None, 2]
[0, None, None, 1, 2, None]
[0, None, None, 1, None, 2]
[0, None, None, None, 1, 2]
[None, 0, 1, 2, None, None]
[None, 0, 1, None, 2, None]
[None, 0, 1, None, None, 2]
[None, 0, None, 1, 2, None]
[None, 0, None, 1, None, 2]
[None, 0, None, None, 1, 2]
[None, None, 0, 1, 2, None]
[None, None, 0, 1, None, 2]
[None, None, 0, None, 1, 2]
[None, None, None, 0, 1, 2]
```

Ideally, you would want to generalize it for arbitrary N, so that you don't have to hard-code `j1`, `j2`, and `j3` indices.